# Is hive partitioning hierarchical in nature?

Tags: hive

Say we have a table partitioned as:-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MyTable (
col1 string,
col2 string,
col3 string
)
PARTITIONED BY(year INT, month INT, day INT, hour INT, combination_id BIGINT);
```

Now obviously year is going to store year value (e.g. 2016), the month will store month va.ue (e.g. 7) the day will store day (e.g. 18) and hour will store hour value in 24 hour format (e.g. 13). And combination_id is going to be combination of padded (if single digit value pad it with 0 on left) values for all these. So in this case for example the combination id is 2016071813.

So we fire query (lets call it **Query A**):-

```
select * from mytable where combination_id = 2016071813
```

Now Hive doesn't know that combination_id is actually combination of year,month,day and hour. So will this query not take proper advantage of partitioning?

In other words, if I have another query, call it **Query B**, will this be more optimal than query A or there is no difference?:-

```
select * from mytable where year=2016 and month=7 and day=18 and hour=13
```

If Hive partitioning scheme is really hierarchical in nature then Query B should be better from performance point of view is what I am thinking. Actually I want to decide whether to get rid of combination_id altogether from partitioning scheme if it is not contributing to better performance at all.

The only real advantage for using combination id is to be able to use **BETWEEN** operator in select:-

```
select * from mytable where combination_id between 2016071813 and 2016071823
```

But if this is not going to take advantage of partitioning scheme, it is going to hamper performance.

Comment: Run `explain select ....` for both queries, and inspect the execution plan. That should give you some clues about how the Hive optimizer does "partition pruning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Hive partitioning is hierarchical.
You can simply check this by printing the partitions of the table using below query.

```
show partitions MyTable;
```

**Output:**

```
year=2016/month=5/day=5/hour=5/combination_id=2016050505
year=2016/month=5/day=5/hour=6/combination_id=2016050506
year=2016/month=5/day=5/hour=7/combination_id=2016050507
```

In your scenario, you don't need to specify combination_id as partition column if you are not using for querying.

You can partition either by

```
Year, month, day, hour columns
```

or

```
combination_id only
```

Partitioning by Multiple columns helps in performance in grouping operations.

Say if you want to find maximum of a col1 for 'March' month of the years (2016 & 2015).

It can easily fetch the records by going to the specific 'Year' partition(year=2016/2015) and month partition(month=3)

Comment: So in a situation where you have partition on year,month,day,hour,combination_id  in that order and then you are only querying on partition_id -- it means performance will be poor compared to querying on year,month,day,hour (in that sequence) right?

Comment: Right. In your case, if you know the combination_id, then you know the year, month, day, hour. So It is better to query on the specific columns of year, month,.. with partitioning on those columns